# toggle not displayed down and up probebly

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidedown

I am facing problem with toggle button..If I click the img it should be space down the img button which contains the content..I tried this code

```
<script>
            $(".image").click(function () {
                $(this).next(".crp-list").toggle();

                $(this).css(".crp-list", "margin-bottom:50px;");
            });
        </script>
```

the code doesn't work .. also if I tried to control with css

.crp-list
{

```
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
padding: 0px;
list-style: none;
top: 52px;
margin-bottom:50px;
clear:both;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

your css syntax is wrong. it's may be **`.css(property, value)`**. please provide your html for verification

```
$(this).next(".crp-list").css('margin-bottom' , '50px');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".image").click(function () {
  var next= $(this).next(".crp-list");      
         next.toggle();
         next.css('margin-bottom' , '50px'); //use css methods to add property
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong JQuery selector for element with `class="crp-list"`.

This is wrong `$(this).css(".crp-list", "margin-bottom:50px;");`. You cannot pass selector and css property in single JQuery function call.

You need to select element first and then apply css on it. Please see below code:

```
<script>
      $(".image").click(function () {
          var crp_list =  $(this).next(".crp-list");
          $(crp_list).toggle();
          $(crp_list).css("margin-bottom","50px");
       });
</script>
```

See [this](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for more information on css.